# Should I track 'snapshots' from JEST?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Or can I remove it from git? Beacuse it is annoying to add new commit just beacuse `index.test.js.snap` changed...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The idea is that you put them into git, and next time the test is run it compares the result against the snapshot. If it gets the same result as the snapshot it will pass otherwise it fails. Without having the snapshots in git the whole concept would make no sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification!